# Comparison between to identical string fails

Tags: php, string, comparison

When I compare two strings, PHP acts like they don't match.

After searching for the problem I now have remove all the invisible characters in my strings.

Here is the code which lets me think my strings are identical

```php
$comp = $values[0] == "‏Id" ? true : false;  
var_dump($comp, $values[0], "Id");
```

The response is

```
boolean false  
string 'Id' (length=2)  
string 'Id' (length=2)
```

Edit : I also checked on http://asciivalue.com/index.php that the ASCII characters of my strings are identical

Comment: In your comparison (the ` == "Id"` bit), there's a weird character by the looks of it.

Comment: You can see from c+p your code here https://3v4l.org/CauCs

Answer (score 0):

[image: It seems like you have a character before string <code>Id</code>]

It seems like you have a character before string `Id`

```
bool(false)
int(3)
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @Jonnix, problem solved.
The "Id" string still had an invisible character.

Thanks !